# How to include a file in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an xml file, inside views folder and I want read it, before I load the view. 
for example

```
views 
    default/
         info.xml
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Simple. Load the file using this

```
$xmlData = $this -> load -> file("application/views/default/info.xml", true);
```

Now use the data, where needed.